# Loop through specific set of directories

Tags: shell, scripting, directory, xml

The following code loops through ALL directories under current path to perform a count on compressed xml files:

```
for i in *xml.gz; do 
    echo "XML" "${PWD##*/}" "$i" $(gunzip -c $i | echo "scale=0; `wc -l`" | bc -l); 
done
```

I'm looking for a way to perform the loop say on the last 5 directories in order to prevent counting directories previously counted (and cut back execution time) The for loop allows specifying certain directories, but I still need to only count xml files. Can't find any syntax to do both.

Comment: IMHO the script look only in current directory: for i in *xml.gz

Comment: That `gunzip | echo "scale=0; `wc -l`" | bc -l` looks like a Rube Goldberg machine, does it do something different from just `gunzip | wc -l` ?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to list last N files based on the time you can use this idea:

```
ls -tr
```

to get newest files on the bottom of the listing

```
tail -5
```

to get last 5 lines. So the code will be something like

```
for i in `ls -tr|tail -5`.....
```

Comment: Well the actual script is:for i in \*xml.gz; do 
    echo "XML" "${PWD##*/}" "$i" $(gunzip -c $i | echo "scale=0; `wc -l`" | bc -l); 
done    (note the backslash at position 1 is not displayed somehow in the post)

Comment: @blom0344, I still can't see the backslash you mention. Do you want to tell me the script is something like: for i in */xml.gz.....? Please edit your question